# close tiny box pop up on click outside of popup

Tags: javascript, popup, tinybox2

Hi I am using tiny box for our website popups ,Its working fine & also working the  closing of it while click on cross button in right top most section of popup.

But I want to add one more functionality in it (like similar to advertisement popup ),I just want when user clicks any where on screen instead of popup the popup should close no need to close it by only click on cross button.

I  am sharing my tinybox.js code file so that it will easy for me to understand where needs to change.Thanks for showing intrest:

```
    TINY={};

TINY.box=function(){
    var j,m,b,g,v,p=0;
    return{
        show:function(o){
            v={opacity:70,close:1,animate:1,fixed:1,mask:1,maskid:'',boxid:'',topsplit:2,url:0,post:0,height:0,width:0,html:0,iframe:0};
            for(s in o){v[s]=o[s]}
            if(!p){
                j=document.createElement('div'); j.className='tbox';
                p=document.createElement('div'); p.className='tinner';
                b=document.createElement('div'); b.className='tcontent';
                m=document.createElement('div'); m.className='tmask';
                g=document.createElement('div'); g.className='tclose'; g.v=0;
                document.body.appendChild(m); document.body.appendChild(j); j.appendChild(p); p.appendChild(b);
                g.onclick=TINY.box.hide; window.onresize=TINY.box.resize
            }else{
                j.style.display='none'; clearTimeout(p.ah); if(g.v){p.removeChild(g); g.v=0}
            }
            p.id=v.boxid; m.id=v.maskid; j.style.position=v.fixed?'fixed':'absolute';
            if(v.html&&!v.animate){
                p.style.backgroundImage='none'; b.innerHTML=v.html; b.style.display='';
                p.style.width=v.width?v.width+'px':'auto'; p.style.height=v.height?v.height+'px':'auto'
            }else{
                b.style.display='none'; 
                if(!v.animate&&v.width&&v.height){
                    p.style.width=v.width+'px'; p.style.height=v.height+'px'
                }else{
                    p.style.width=p.style.height='100px'
                }
            }
            if(v.mask){this.mask(); this.alpha(m,1,v.opacity)}else{this.alpha(j,1,100)}
            if(v.autohide){p.ah=setTimeout(TINY.box.hide,1000*v.autohide)}else{document.onkeyup=TINY.box.esc}
        },
        fill:function(c,u,k,a,w,h){
            if(u){
                if(v.image){
                    var i=new Image(); i.onload=function(){w=w||i.width; h=h||i.height; TINY.box.psh(i,a,w,h)}; i.src=v.image
                }else if(v.iframe){
                    this.psh('<iframe src="'+v.iframe+'" width="'+v.width+'" frameborder="0" height="'+v.height+'"></iframe>',a,w,h)
                }else{
                    var x=window.XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                    x.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        if(x.readyState==4&&x.status==200){p.style.backgroundImage=''; TINY.box.psh(x.responseText,a,w,h)}
                    };
                    if(k){
                        x.open('POST',c,true); x.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); x.send(k)
                    }else{
                        x.open('GET',c,true); x.send(null)
                    }
                }
            }else{
                this.psh(c,a,w,h)
            }
        },
        psh:function(c,a,w,h){
            if(typeof c=='object'){b.appendChild(c)}else{b.innerHTML=c}
            var x=p.style.width, y=p.style.height;
            if(!w||!h){
                p.style.width=w?w+'px':''; p.style.height=h?h+'px':''; b.style.display='';
                if(!h){h=parseInt(b.offsetHeight)}
                if(!w){w=parseInt(b.offsetWidth)}
                b.style.display='none'
            }
            p.style.width=x; p.style.height=y;
            this.size(w,h,a)
        },
        esc:function(e){e=e||window.event; if(e.keyCode==27){TINY.box.hide()}},
        hide:function(){TINY.box.alpha(j,-1,0,3); document.onkeypress=null; if(v.closejs){v.closejs()}},
        resize:function(){TINY.box.pos(); TINY.box.mask()},
        mask:function(){m.style.height=this.total(1)+'px'; m.style.width=this.total(0)+'px'},
        pos:function(){
            var t;
            if(typeof v.top!='undefined'){t=v.top}else{t=(this.height()/v.topsplit)-(j.offsetHeight/2); t=t<20?20:t}
            if(!v.fixed&&!v.top){t+=this.top()}
            j.style.top=t+'px'; 
            j.style.left=typeof v.left!='undefined'?v.left+'px':(this.width()/2)-(j.offsetWidth/2)+'px'
        },
        alpha:function(e,d,a){
            clearInterval(e.ai);
            if(d){e.style.opacity=0; e.style.filter='alpha(opacity=0)'; e.style.display='block'; TINY.box.pos()}
            e.ai=setInterval(function(){TINY.box.ta(e,a,d)},20)
        },
        ta:function(e,a,d){
            var o=Math.round(e.style.opacity*100);
            if(o==a){
                clearInterval(e.ai);
                if(d==-1){
                    e.style.display='none';
                    e==j?TINY.box.alpha(m,-1,0,2):b.innerHTML=p.style.backgroundImage=''
                }else{
                    if(e==m){
                        this.alpha(j,1,100)
                    }else{
                        j.style.filter='';
                        TINY.box.fill(v.html||v.url,v.url||v.iframe||v.image,v.post,v.animate,v.width,v.height)
                    }
                }
            }else{
                var n=a-Math.floor(Math.abs(a-o)*.5)*d;
                e.style.opacity=n/100; e.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+n+')'
            }
        },
        size:function(w,h,a){
            if(a){
                clearInterval(p.si); var wd=parseInt(p.style.width)>w?-1:1, hd=parseInt(p.style.height)>h?-1:1;
                p.si=setInterval(function(){TINY.box.ts(w,wd,h,hd)},20)
            }else{
                p.style.backgroundImage='none'; if(v.close){p.appendChild(g); g.v=1}
                p.style.width=w+'px'; p.style.height=h+'px'; b.style.display=''; this.pos();
                if(v.openjs){v.openjs()}
            }
        },
        ts:function(w,wd,h,hd){
            var cw=parseInt(p.style.width), ch=parseInt(p.style.height);
            if(cw==w&&ch==h){
                clearInterval(p.si); p.style.backgroundImage='none'; b.style.display='block'; if(v.close){p.appendChild(g); g.v=1}
                if(v.openjs){v.openjs()}
            }else{
                if(cw!=w){p.style.width=(w-Math.floor(Math.abs(w-cw)*.6)*wd)+'px'}
                if(ch!=h){p.style.height=(h-Math.floor(Math.abs(h-ch)*.6)*hd)+'px'}
                this.pos()
            }
        },
        top:function(){return document.documentElement.scrollTop||document.body.scrollTop},
        width:function(){return self.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth||document.body.clientWidth},
        height:function(){return self.innerHeight||document.documentElement.clientHeight||document.body.clientHeight},
        total:function(d){
            var b=document.body, e=document.documentElement;
            return d?Math.max(Math.max(b.scrollHeight,e.scrollHeight),Math.max(b.clientHeight,e.clientHeight)):
            Math.max(Math.max(b.scrollWidth,e.scrollWidth),Math.max(b.clientWidth,e.clientWidth))
        },

    }
}();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the code to hide the pop up when clicked on the mask i.e. `m.onclick`.

You have already declared the hide functionality for the close button using,

```
g=document.createElement('div'); g.className='tclose';
```

and

```
g.onclick=TINY.box.hide;
```

now you just need to add `m.onclick` like this,

```
m.onclick=g.onclick=TINY.box.hide;
```

FYI, this is the default setting in `tinybox.js`.
I hope it will solve your problem.